# I am trying to ssh to a windows machine from ansible, the program gets stuck

Tags: ssh, ansible

tasks:

```
name: Connect to Windows hpst machine through an ssh script
script : windows_connect.ssh
name: Run the bat file
script : C:\OV\sentenv.bat
name: To exit from the remote machine
shell: exit
```

This is what my playbook looks like.

`Windows_connect.sh` contains a script to connect to a windows machine via ssh.

```
ssh root@host
```

So ideally shouldnt ansible prompt me for a password?
Instead it gets stuck.

Please help me with the same

Comment: Thats no valid tasks definition. *If* this is working you have not copied it correctly. Please update your question with your working playbook content.

Comment: ---


- hosts: 16.184.41.150
  tasks:
   - name: Connect to Windows host machine through an ssh script
     shell: windows_connect.ssh
   - name: Run the bat file
     shell : mkdir -p /home/Parvathy/trial
   - name: To exit from the remote machine
     shell: exit
  vars_prompt:

   - name: "release_version"
     prompt: "Product release version"
     default: "1.0"
...

Comment: This is the exact yml file! Sorry about the format

Answer (score 1):

Ansible opens at least one new ssh connection for every task in the play.

So the idea to open a ssh connection with the first task and then reuse the connection in the later tasks will not work. Actually Ansible won't be able to execute the first task because the [script module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html) you are trying to use will already need a working connection to the remote host.

I have found little information on how many ssh connection Ansible will use to execute a task so I might be wrong here.

You should consult the [Ansible documentation for Window support](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html) and implement a solution based on the `winrm` Python module.